# shiny dashboard -sidebarMenu with menuItem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a shiny application using sidebarMenu with menuItems.  Currently the menu items are duplicated,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATqGg.png)

Clicking the first and second menu items are not showing the table or the plot.  Only the last two shows the output.  How can I modify it to have only two items - 1) Plots Menu, 2) Table Menu (with sub items) and clicking on it show the respective output.  Used the `mtcars` dataset and the code ispasted below

```
data(mtcars)
ibrary(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

 ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Plots Menu", tabName = "plot_page", icon = icon("line-chart")),

        menuItem("Table Menu", tabName="intro_page", icon = icon("info"),
                 selectInput(inputId = "mcm", label = "Some label",
                             multiple = TRUE, choices = unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)))

      ),
      sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
    ),
    dashboardBody(tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "plots", h2("Dashboard plots"),
              fluidRow(column(width = 12, class = "well",
                              h4("Boxplot"),
                              plotOutput("bxp")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content"),
              dataTableOutput(outputId = "subdt"))
    )
    )
  )



  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$menu <- renderMenu({
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Plots Menu", tabName = "plots", icon = icon("line-chart")),

        menuItem("Table Menu", tabName="dashboard", icon = icon("calendar"))
      )
    })

    datsub <- reactive({
      mtcars %>%
          filter_at(vars("cyl"), all_vars(. %in% input$mcm))


    })

    output$subdt <- renderDataTable({
      datsub()
    })

    output$bxp <- renderPlot({

      hist(rnorm(100))


    }) 

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both the standard and reactive sidebar options running in tandem. If you need a reactive sidebar, just put the contents in the `server` function and call all of it with `sidebarMenuOutput` in `ui`.

### `ui.R`

```
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "menu", sidebarMenuOutput("menu")))
```

### `server.R`

```
output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Plots Menu", tabName = "plots", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Table Menu", icon = icon("info"),
               menuSubItem(
                 "Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("calendar")
               ),
               selectInput(
                 inputId = "mcm", label = "Some label", multiple = TRUE,
                 choices = unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)
               )
      )
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I put the code together.
-Ian

```
data(mtcars)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "menu", sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems
    (
    tabItem
      (tabName = "plots", h2("Dashboard plots"),
    fluidRow(column(width = 12, class = "well",
    h4("Boxplot"),
    plotOutput("bxp")))
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content"),
    dataTableOutput(outputId = "subdt"))
  )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Plots Menu", tabName = "plots", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Table Menu", icon = icon("info"),
               menuSubItem(
                 "Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("calendar")
               ),
               selectInput(
                 inputId = "mcm", label = "Some label", multiple = TRUE,
                 choices = unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)
               )
      )
    )
  })

  datsub <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%
      filter_at(vars("cyl"), all_vars(. %in% input$mcm))
  })

  output$subdt <- renderDataTable({
    datsub()
  })

  output$bxp <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(100))
  }) 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```